# How to extract current chrome browsing session from HDD of a broken laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, google-chrome, session

The HDD is OK. I am accessing it via SATA-USB cable on a different computer.

I have extracted all data before I will send it to repair but I had some important tabs open and I would like to find my current browsing session.

Where is that stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's stored in Chrome's profile. The profile resides in:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
```

You can copy this entire folder and restore it on another PC to the same location (username can differ).

You can get permission issues while copying because the old profile is owned by another user. You can change owner and permissions in folder's properties. (This won't be an issue if you'll be moving the profile with an intermediate FAT32-formatted media, such as most flash drives.)

### but...

If you were signed in to Chrome, there's a chance that your tabs were synced to Google's servers. Go to *History* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and click *Tabs from other devices* on the left. If you had your tabs synced to the same Google account that you're currently signed into, you'll see your tabs.

Comment: I don't understand. I've found the folder but it's full of other folders and files, none of which seem to hold the current browsing session :(

Comment: @gronostaj Perhaps you should edit the answer and explicitly mention that the said folder is to copied to the same location in the new computer? The OP is worried about other users assumptions and missed the point completely...

Comment: I'd also change:
1. The folder in my case was: C:\Users\tk198\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data (maybe it can differ between users?)
2. While attempting to access it, due to what I am doing (external HDD from another machine), windows tries to save the day and block access  to the HDD. Need to go to the folder properties > Security > Advanced and just click OK for it to apply the new administration privileges.
I'll accept the answer. Thanks